# Send email on image click in joomla

Tags: joomla

hey I am new to joomla and I want to send an email to a user when an image is clicked(I got two images so a different mail for each)
how can it be done?

Comment: Please try: <a href="mailto:your_email_here"><img src="your_image_here"></a>

Comment: I need to send email to a user not him to me

Comment: How will you get user's mail, is there an input box to put that?

Comment: I am using the  protostar build in login system, when a user registers he enters his mail, I want to use this mail.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hyperlink in Joomla on the image (click the image then the chain icon) and in the URL box, type mailto:email@domain.com and then when clicked it will open the default mail editor with the recipient box filled... is that kind of what you needed?

Comment: Not what I meant. the user is registered with an email. so I want to send his email a message lets say "image 1 selected" or "image 2 selected " and I want to add to a database that the user selected this image